# How to Connect Mongodb to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

I am unable to Connect to PHP with mongodb. I am getting an error:

> Fatal error: Mongo Class not Found.

Please tell me about this and how to fix this problem.

Comment: Show us the PHP code that connects to the database

Comment: Try this simple tutorial, hope that can help you [http://makble.com/crud-in-mongodb-with-php](http://makble.com/crud-in-mongodb-with-php)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and read [ask].

Comment: Please review the Stackoverflow guide on how to ask good questions, don't make us play the game of 20 questions with you, since this is a library issue we need to know what operating system you are using, what version of PHP and mongodb you are using, we need the code, and we need the steps you used to reproduce this error.  You've given us none of that.  Read: http://sscce.org

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Connect to MongoDB
    $conn = new Mongo('localhost');

    // connect to test database
    $db = $conn->test;

    // a new products collection object
    $collection = $db->products;
```